# firebasestorage.googleapis.com bad request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I noticed that my uploaded files became unavailable yesterday morning. I didn't change the settings.
It doesn't work in browsers and mobile apps, but it is wired because it works in different regions.
I tried to run the `curl -I https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket...` but I just got the HTTP/2 400 error and nothing else. When I link an URL for example into the Slack chat, then the URL works but when I try to open it from a browser or in a mobile application it doesn't work.

I got this message.
[image]

UPDATE: It works from VPN and 4g but doesn't work on wifi. This is totally weird.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused because your ISP is blocking connections to Firebase. There other user who have [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/204788350) the same issue with Hungarian Telekom mobile (¿is that the ISP you are using?). The solution is to contact the ISP and tell them to allow those connections. This also explains why using a VPN works.

Comment: Thank you. I send the same bug report what you linked :D